Edit legend of seaborn stacked barplot
I followed this tutorial to create a stacked double barplot, which worked nicely for my data, but now I'm trying to edit the legend to include the information needed to read the figure. I tried following this answer but it just creates a new legend over the original one.

What I would like to see in my legend is
blue -> raw
orange -> spike
hatched -> CATTCCA
blank -> CATTCCT

Any ideas of how to achieve this?
Here's my data:
Conds method peaks motif_CATTCCA motif_CATTCCT
TEAD1_T1_pos_1 raw_only 22424 2376 1357
TEAD1_T1_pos_1 spike_only 4086 975 246
TEAD1_T1_pos_2 raw_only 59922 6907 3899
TEAD1_T1_pos_2 spike_only 1064 611 63
TEAD1_T7_neg_1 raw_only 5650 745 346
TEAD1_T7_neg_1 spike_only 16340 2458 984
TEAD1_T7_neg_2 raw_only 64300 7812 4407
TEAD1_T7_neg_2 spike_only 662 406 29
TEAD1_T7_pos_1 raw_only 49892 4894 3109
TEAD1_T7_pos_1 spike_only 1106 598 55
TEAD1_T7_pos_2 raw_only 22666 2325 1403
TEAD1_T7_pos_2 spike_only 4558 1002 259


and the code:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sns

workdir = "my/dir/"

data = pd.read_csv(workdir + "motifs_under_peaks.txt", sep=" ")

data_pct = data.copy()
data_pct["motif_CATTCCA"] = data_pct["motif_CATTCCA"] / data_pct["peaks"]
data_pct["motif_CATTCCT"] = data_pct["motif_CATTCCT"] / data_pct["peaks"]
data_pct = data_pct.drop("peaks", 1)
data_pct = data_pct.melt(id_vars=["Conds", "method"], var_name="motif")

total = data_pct.groupby(["Conds", "method"])["value"].sum().reset_index()
motif_A = data_pct[data_pct.motif =="motif_CATTCCA"]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

bar1 = sns.barplot(x="value", y="Conds", hue="method", data=total, ax=ax1)
bar2 = sns.barplot(x="value", y="Conds", hue="method", data=motif_A, hatch="xxxxx", ax=ax1) ##need to add hatching into legend

fig1.legend(title="motif enrichment", loc="upper right", labels=["raw CATTCCT", "spike CATTCCT", "raw CATTCCA", "spike CATTCCA"])



why would your legend show "raw CATTCCT"/"spike CATTCCT" when it's in fact the CATTCCT+CATTCCA total?

To rename the legend, simply access the existing legend with Axes.get_legend and set the title with set_title:
ax1.get_legend().set_title('motif enrichment')

Output:

If you want several modification I would recommend to directly produce the DataFrames with the correct values/columns and not having to change the legend afterwards. For this rename/replace the columns/strings and seaborn will automatically use the desired names:
data_pct = (data_pct.melt(id_vars=['Conds', 'method'], var_name='motif')
            .rename(columns={'method': 'motif enrichment'})
           )


total = (data_pct.groupby(['Conds', 'motif enrichment'])['value'].sum()
         .rename({'raw_only': 'raw CATTCCT',
                  'spike_only': 'spike CATTCCT'
                 })
         .reset_index()
        )
motif_A = (data_pct[data_pct.motif =='motif_CATTCCA']
           .replace({'motif enrichment': {'raw_only': 'raw CATTCCA',
                                          'spike_only': 'spike CATTCCA'}})
          )

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()

bar1 = sns.barplot(x='value', y='Conds', hue='motif enrichment', data=total, ax=ax1)
bar2 = sns.barplot(x='value', y='Conds', hue='motif enrichment', data=motif_A, hatch='xxxxx', ax=ax1) ##need to add hatching into legend

Output:


I need to change more than the title of the legend

@Whitehot I missed that, but why don't you directly set the correct columns names? Then seaborn will use what you want and you won't have to change anything.

I added an update to show you how you could rename/replace the values prior to plotting.

You should set the legend in the ax1 object:
# get the legend handles to preserve the boxes and hatching
handles, _ = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()

# add legend with correct title and labels
ax1.legend(
   handles=handles,
   title="motif enrichment",
   labels=["raw CATTCCT", "spike CATTCCT", "raw CATTCCA", "spike CATTCCA"],
)


